# Setting Content-Security-Policy inside of a Khan Academy html program. To be able to access html files inside of Khan Academy

Tags: javascript, html, request, httprequest, khan-academy

I want to make an html program in Khan Academy that uses http requests to get an html file from Khan Academy. I've done this offline but I need to do it in Khan Academy.
CSP is Content-Security-Policy

The problem is I don't know how to set headers in CSP, on another server. How can **you** make it work so the html project can get html5 files from Khan Academy and put them into a string?

Don't just tell me the answer, show me what a working CSP header/example looks like in that program. Then copy and paste the code from this link: https://www.khanacademy.org/computer-programming/ka-download-test/4522352506732544
and show me what a working example looks like.

**Edit**:
What I meant was go to this link: https://www.khanacademy.org/computer-programming/ka-download-test/4522352506732544. Then go into the top of the html and change line 5, until it works or you see no more errors in the *debugger's console.*

Comment: What does "CSP" mean?

Comment: You cannot set them on an "other" server, only on your own server that you control. Since you don't seem to own Khan Academy: no, not possible.

Comment: @Pointy Content Security Policy would be my guess

Comment: Content Security Policy is what I meant.

Comment: Ah OK thx, should have known :)